# Trying to create countdown Timer in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, timer

I am trying to create a timer for when my xaml page loads it starts a four minute timer and when it gets to 0 have the program stop and start again. having an issue creating the timer. Using DispatcherTimer in VB.net to get result. Code below:

```
Private Sub Timer_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim time = New Threading.DispatcherTimer()
    time.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
    AddHandler time.Tick, AddressOf time_tick
    time.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub time_tick(ByVal sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Timer.Text = Date.Now.Second
End Sub
```

Tried putting the time_click as a public sub as doing it inside of the Timer_Loaded xaml event would throw an error. I get the following error when running the code:

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs'.'

Googled a couple fixes, and tried rewriting the timer function. However I can't get passed this issue. Also tried putting the content tag of the text box right in the address of however the Address of only takes methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A handler of the DispatcherTimer's Tick event only accepts an event argument of type System.EventArgs:

```
Public Sub time_tick(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Timer.Text = Date.Now.Second
End Sub
```

Check out this outstanding article on the topic:  http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/timer-in-wpf-using-vb.net

Comment: I think this will point me in the right direction. I just now need to figure out the best way to put it into a countdown timer. Thanks

Comment: does it answer your question?

Comment: System.Windows.Threading *is* part of WPF. DispatcherTimer *is* a WPF class.